# How to access a specific object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to this. I am using JSON to define a class/object called `product` and I am not sure how to pass arguments to access a certain part of that object. Pardon me for not being able to explain it better. Hopefully my code sample will help:

```
var product = {
    p14lb: {
        one: 10.00,
        two: 20.00,
        three: 30.00,
        four: 40.00,
        five: 50.00,
        six: 60.00,
        colorCharge: 2.00
    },
    p20lb: {
        one: 20.00,
        two: 30.00,
        three: 40.00,
        four: 50.00,
        five: 60.00,
        six: 70.00,
        colorCharge: 1.00
    },
    getPrice: function (productQty,colorQty) {

        // I can get the values like this        
        return this.p20lb.one * productQty;

        // but i'd like to be able to pass in the value of what object I want to access
        // so instead of hard coding p20lb.one, 'p20lb' would be an argument I could pass
        // to getPrice, and 'one' would also be an argument

    }
};
```

This is how I am accessing it currently, works great.

```
var myProduct = product.getPrice(144,2);
```

As I said in the comment in the above code sample, I'd like to **not** hard code p20lb.one, 'p20lb' would be an argument I could pass to getPrice, and 'one' would also be an argument. So maybe something like this:

```
getPrice: function (productQty,colorQty,productName,tier) {

    return this.productName.tier * productQty;

}

var myProduct = product.getPrice(144,2,'14lb','two');
```

But that is no go, I get `undefined` no matter what I do. I'm clearly a noob when it comes to this. Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: BTW: What you refer to is called "object literal", not JSON. JSON is a [very strict string format](http://json.org/) that can be understood by JavaScript's `eval()`. Your sample is valid JavaScript, but definitely not JSON-compliant.

Comment: +1 Cool, thanks for that! I was using this as reference (see #2) http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Ah, and now that I read the comments on the article I linked, someone also pointed that out to the author, too. Good to know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `this[productName][tier]` instead. In JavaScript, the dot notation and bracket notation are identical. That is, `obj.a` is the same as `obj['a']`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
getPrice: function (productQty,colorQty,productName,tier) {

    return this[productName][tier] * productQty;

}
```

Objects can be accessed in array notation. Don't forget to wrap it in a try-catch block to handle the cases where a certain key combination does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do:

```
var colorQty = product.p20lb.one;
var myProduct = product.getPrice(144, colorQty);

getPrice: function (productQty, colorQty) {
    return productQty * colorQty;
}
```